# AngularJS how to bind the ng-model on $watch

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using ionic framework and in my search module I'm using a library called ion-autocomplete https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete trying to bind the ng-model to my scope but I can't get it to bind.

Controller:

```
$scope.model = "";
$scope.callbackMethod = function (query) {
   //scope.model doesn't bind
   return PostService.SearchUser($scope.model, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token, -1, -1)
   .success(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   })
   .error(function(error) {

   });
};
```

View:

```
//this derective is an input field
<ion-autocomplete ng-model="model" items-method="callbackMethod(query)" placeholder="Enter something"/>
```

---

Template:

```
var template = '<input type="search" class="ion-autocomplete-search" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/>'
```

Directive:

```
.directive('ionAutocomplete', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" />',
        replace: true
    }

});
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. My guess is that your autocomplete is inside an ng-if or ng-repeat (or any other directive that creates its own scope. Use `$scope.model = {foo: ''};` and `ng-model="model.foo"`.

Comment: i tried your solution it didn't work.. this is the separate directive you're talking about <input type="search" class="ion-autocomplete-search" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"/> i tried searchQuery as scope didn't work as well.. I just want to know how to bind it while $watch

Comment: My solution is only a guess. My comment started with "Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.". Do it.

Comment: Your input doesn't have any ng-model directive attached to it. Why would it bind anything to the scope? Don't write a directive just for that. It doesn't do anything that the input + ion-autocomplete directives do already.

Comment: i binded the $scope.searchQuery would that make sense.. still didn't work though

Comment: Please have a look at the demo here how to properly bind the model and the `items-method`: https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#demo If you still have an issue with this please create an issue here such that I can have a look at it: https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete/issues. Why do you need to pass the `model` to the `PostService.SearchUser()` method? Because the `model` is populated by the `ion-autocomplete` directive.